# C Union definition

Tags: c

Within a struct I need some space where I can put in something. This space have to be able to collect all data types, so I want to define an union. The space is limited to n bytes (unsigned char).

How do I have to define my union, so that it can contain char, int, float and so on?

Have I to do it this way?

```
#define SIZE (128)
union {
        unsigned char uchar[SIZE];
        char schar[SIZE];
        unsigned int uint[SIZE/sizeof(unsigned int)];
        int sint[SIZE/sizeof(int)];
        float flt[SIZE/sizeof(float)];
        double dbl[SIZE/sizeof(double)];
}memory;
```

Or is there a possibility to define only the size of the unsigned char array and then to define size of the int array automatically? What does happen, if `SIZE` isn't divisible by 4?

**EDIT:** (related to the comments)

I want to build something like an timed event handler. That means, I have a struct containing an array of events. Each event has an execution time and a related function (stored as a pointer). When the timer counter of the event handler matches the event execution time, I call the related function. Within the function I will know, wich arguments are expected, so I don't need to save a tag value. The problem is, that the events are created within a funtion and because I don't want to make the events static (to save memory), I added some memory (ring buffer) to my event handler where all functions can put in some data. Each event will have a variable containing the pointer to the (first) data. The type of data are only the nativ data types, no own structs.

This is my current code:

`startSystemClock()` will be called at start up

`executeSystemEvent()` will be called by the interrupt service routine of timer 1 by setting `sysEventHandler.execute=TRUE` and a `while(1)`-loop checks this flag and then calls `executeSystemEvent()`

```
// typedefs requird for timed events
typedef union __attribute__ ((packed)){
    int *i;     // pointer, where data is stored
    int value;  // if there is a pointer assigned, value differs from zero
}systemEventData_u;

typedef union __attribute__ ((packed)){
    int value;  // if there is a pointer assigned, value differs from zero
    void (*voidFct_noData)();
    void (*voidFct_data)(systemEventData_u);
}systemEventFct_u;

typedef struct{
    int time;
    unsigned int id;
    systemEventFct_u fct;
    systemEventData_u data;
}systemEvent_t;

#define SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE    (10)
#define SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_MEMORY_SIZE    (10)
typedef struct{
    unsigned int actualCnt;
    unsigned int nextEventCnt;
    unsigned char execute;
    systemEvent_t events[SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE];
    systemEvent_t* write;
    // create some persistent memory usable by all functions
    int* memWrite;
    union __attribute__ ((packed)){
        unsigned char uchar[0];
        char schar[0];
        unsigned int uint[0];
        int sint[SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_MEMORY_SIZE];
        float flt[0];
        double dbl[0];
    }memory;
}systemEventHandler_t;

void startSystemClock(){
    // initialize event handler
    sysEventHandler.actualCnt=0;
    sysEventHandler.nextEventCnt=-1;
    sysEventHandler.execute=FALSE;
    sysEventHandler.write=sysEventHandler.events;
    sysEventHandler.memWrite=sysEventHandler.memory.sint;
    unsigned int i=SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE;
    systemEvent_t *ptr=sysEventHandler.events;
    while(i--){
        ptr->fct.value=0;
        ptr->data.value=0;
        ptr->time=0;
        ptr++;
    }
    // initialize timer 1
    TMR1 = 0x00;
    T1CON =  T3_OFF | T3_IDLE_CON | T3_GATE_OFF | T1_PS_1_8 | T1_SOURCE_INT;
    IPC1SET = (INTERRUPT_PRIOR_TIMER1 << _IPC1_T1IP_POSITION) | (INTERRUPT_SUB_PRIOR_TIMER1 << _IPC1_T1IS_POSITION);
    IFS0CLR = (1 << _IFS0_T1IF_POSITION);
    IEC0SET = (1 << _IEC0_T1IE_POSITION);
    PR1 = PR_TIMER1;
    T1CONSET = (1 << _T1CON_ON_POSITION);
    print_text("timer1 started\n\r");
}

void executeSystemEvent(){
    asm("di");
    int time=sysEventHandler.actualCnt;
    asm("ei");
    unsigned int i=SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE;
    unsigned int nextEventCnt=-1;
    systemEvent_t *ptr=sysEventHandler.events;
    while(i--){
        // do not investigate, if there is no function pointer
        // no function pointer means no event action
        if(ptr->fct.value){
            if(time>=ptr->time){
                // execute function
                if(ptr->data.value){
                    (*ptr->fct.voidFct_data)(ptr->data);
                }else{
                    (*ptr->fct.voidFct_noData)();
                }
                ptr->fct.value=0;
            }
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    // determine next event
    // iterate again through whole queue to take added events into account also
    i=SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE;
    ptr=sysEventHandler.events;
    while(i--){
        if(ptr->fct.value){
            // get execution time to determine next one
            if(ptr->time<nextEventCnt){
                nextEventCnt=ptr->time;
            }
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    asm("di");
    sysEventHandler.nextEventCnt=nextEventCnt;
    sysEventHandler.execute=FALSE;
    asm("ei");
}

void addSystemEvent(systemEvent_t event){
    // check, if this event will be the first event to execute
    asm("di");
    // get event execution time
    event.time+=sysEventHandler.actualCnt;
    // check, if it will be the next one to execute
    if(sysEventHandler.nextEventCnt>event.time){
        sysEventHandler.nextEventCnt=event.time;
    }
    asm("ei");
    *sysEventHandler.write=event;
    if(++sysEventHandler.write>=sysEventHandler.events+SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_BUFFER_SIZE){
        sysEventHandler.write=sysEventHandler.events;
    }
}

int * storeSystemEventData(int data){
    int *ptr=sysEventHandler.memWrite;
    *ptr=data;
    if(++sysEventHandler.memWrite>=sysEventHandler.memory.sint+SYSTEM_EVENT_HANDLER_MEMORY_SIZE){
        sysEventHandler.memWrite=sysEventHandler.memory.sint;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

To add an event, I write within any function:

```
systemEvent_t event;
event.fct.voidFct_data=&enablePinChangeInterrupt_wrapper;
event.data.i=storeSystemEventData((int)PUSHBUTTON_CN_BIT);
event.time=10;
addSystemEvent(event);
```

I know, that the `storeSystemEventData`-function isn't complete. But for my first purpose, I only need int, so it works.

Comment: When you say all data types do you mean only the Plain Old Data types such as `int`, etc. or do you also need user defined data types such as `struct`? Do you need to consider other more specific data types such as 32 bit or 64 bit signed/unsigned integers? Do you really need arrays of types other than `char` and `unsigned char` as these arrays are normally used for text strings or is this memory space to be used to contain a text string or a binary number of some kind?

Comment: One other question is how will you know the actual data type stored in the union? Typically a union is used within a struct which contains a tag value or enumeration which indicates the actual data type stored in the union.

Comment: Looks to me like your original union will be fine. May want to use a function hooked into a timer which processes a list of pending events, decrementing the timer count and when zero, executing the event function. The event function then decides if it is a recurring, periodic event which must be reset to count down again or a one time only which must be removed from the timer event list after executing. I would be cautious about disabling interrupts.  Is this a multi-threading application or a single thread handling multiple events? What OS support do you have for synchronization and timers?

Comment: the program is running on a PIC32MX795F512L microcontroller. There is no OS, no Threads and so on....

The timer raises an interrupt an within the interrupt I count up the time. Becuase the time requiered to execute the interrupt has to be small, I don't want to count down the time of each event.

I put an event into a circular buffer. When the event should be executed periodically, the funtion called from the event will put in the event in the queue again.

Comment: But I think, I will define the size of the union using `int[..]` , all others ..[0] and always count up the `int`-pointer, even if I put in a char. Sure, this isn't the most efficient way to do so, because in the case of put in a char, I will "waste" 3 bytes. But one advantage is, that the data is aligned to a divisible address....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the array sizes except for the biggest.  Just out-of-bounds access the other types.

```
#include "stdio.h"

union memory {
    unsigned char uchar[128];
    char schar[0];
    unsigned int uint[0];
    int sint[0];
    float flt[0];
    double dbl[0];
} ;

int main (void)
{
    union memory my_mem;
    my_mem.schar[5] = 'A';
    my_mem.schar[6] = 'B';
    my_mem.schar[7] = 'C';
    my_mem.schar[8] = 'D';

    printf ("%d\n", my_mem.uint[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

C doesn't provide array bounds checking either way, so you're just out of luck if you try to access memory outside the memory object.

Comment: Is it the usual way to set the size of the arrays to zero or is this more a common used "hack"?

Comment: Not that I know of.  There is no common hack because it's very uncommon to write code using unions like this.

Comment: What would be the appropriate way to do what I want?

Comment: If the array size information and the index value is available at the point where an out of bounds access is done some C compilers as well as static analysis tools will provide a warning for an out of bounds access. There are also C IDEs with tools which when compiled in debug mode and when used in debug mode will perform array out of bounds checks.

Comment: I would need a higher-level description of your problem to suggest alternative methods.  "collect all data types" is too vague.

Comment: Rather than have a memory omni-type, just have the event handlers expect an argument of type  `void *` and the event handlers can cast that pointer up to the type they need.  `void *` plus casting is more versatile than any memory type you could write.

Answer (score 2):

> What does happen, if SIZE isn't divisible by 4?

I assume you ask the question about divisibility by 4 (as opposed by any other number) because it is a common `sizeof(int)`. When `SIZE` is indivisible by any of the `sizeof`s, would end up with the largest array that fits fully inside the `size`, i.e. the number would be truncated. For example, setting `SIZE` to `13` when `sizeof(int)` is 4 would produce

```
int sint[3];
```

In other words, the size would be "rounded down" (truncated). If you prefer rounding up, use this expression:

```
unsigned int uint[(SIZE+sizeof(unsigned int)-1)/sizeof(unsigned int)];
```

Note, however, that the size of `uint[]` array may exceed the size of `uchar`.

> is there a possibility to define only the size of the unsigned char array and then to define size of the int array automatically?

You could replace `union` with an array of `char`s, and convert `void*` pointer to `int*`, `float*`, etc. This would lead to a different syntax.

Comment: @nouney In case of aliased arrays `void*` is better, because it provides more clarity to the readers of your code. I often prefer `char*` to `void*` when I need to partition my blocks of memory manually, because `char*` lets me do pointer arithmetic without a cast.

Comment: *You could replace union with an array of chars, and convert void* pointer to int*, float*, etc.*  I'd note that doing so can result in failures such as SIGBUS on architectures with different alignment restrictions for different data types.  Having, for example, an explicit `double` array in the union would avoid that.  Also, as you allude, pointer arithmetic on `void *` is non-standard - I suspect your comment will generate some "But I do pointer arithmetic on `void *` all the time!" thoughts if not actual comments...